# Testing File Streaming in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Any idea how to test file streaming in Cucumber?
Note this is a Java microservice with a client and server architecture.
The client talks to the server on a designated port..I just dont know how to do this?
Most of the examples that I have seen are Browser Based Testing with Selenium.

I am writing Junit test cases for this and I wanted to know how this is to be done.
I am new to Behavior Driven Testing and I find this really exciting!

Answer (score 1):

You have to imagine you are the client and that you are consuming the service. When you use the service what do you get back. If you are cukeing you need to think in business terms e.g. its about WHAT you are doing and WHY its important, not HOW its done. So WHAT is the point of this service, what value does it give.

If you just want to test that it works then I'd use a unit test tool instead.

Comment: Can you comment also on my other simplified question? This mirrors what I am trying to achive actually 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871059/creating-cucumber-test-on-executable-docker-image